# How to use ASPNET BoilerPlate with Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

We are using `.Net Core` template of `ASPNET BoilerPlate` framework. It works fine with SQL Server, but now we need to use Oracle 11g instead. Is it possible? If yes, how can we implement it for our project? Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: [https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EF-Core-Oracle-Integration](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EF-Core-Oracle-Integration)

Comment: Thank Aaron, is there any way to walk around? Can I use ODP.NET that mentioned here :https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/5996

Comment: You can use ODP.NET 18c, as mentioned in your linked question.

Comment: Aaron, I have tried another solution, could you take a look? Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840797/aspnet-boilerplate-use-linked-server-to-oracle-database-issue

Comment: All these questions are about EF Core, not ASP.NET Boilerplate.